# Centering items in a row, when you don't know how many items

Tags: css, columns

I have the following custom query which outputs a set of items inside a container.

```
<div class="container-hotel">
  <?php // The Loop
  if ( $venue_query->have_posts() ) {   while ( $venue_query->have_posts() ) { $venue_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php $venuecounter = 1; ?>

    <div class="item-hotel">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'hotel-single' ); ?><br />
        <?php the_title('<h4 style="text-align:center;">', '</h4>', true); ?>
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php if ($venuecounter % 3 == 0) { ?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php }

$venuecounter++ ;
}
} else { ?>

  something else

<?php } ?>

</div> <!-- /container-hotel -->
```

The following scss ensures they sit 3x across in nice columns.

```
.container-hotel {
  width:78%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
      width: 100%;
  }
}
.item-hotel {
  float: left;
  width:230px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

However, I'd really like to see a different behaviour when there are less than 3 items in the last row. I'd like those to be centred, so instead of

`[item] [item] [item]
[item]`

We'd see

`[item] [item] [item]
        [item]`

and if there were two remaining items,

`[item] [item] [item]
    [item] [item]`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is more of a [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) question than a WordPress question since it's mostly CSS and PHP to define a Layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
.container-hotel {
  width:78%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
      width: 100%;
  }
}
.item-hotel {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  width:230px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Using the auto in parent and inline-block for child did the trick.